# Laravel storage with Docker

Tags: laravel, docker, laravel-storage

I'm setting up Docker for a Laravel app which is an internal CDN with vast amount of images and other static files living in `./storage/app`, both `private` and `public`. I want the Docker image to be built with GitLab CI and my question is what is the right way of building it without overriding the contents of the storage? Those contents aren't present in the repo.

I have two thoughts about that:

- Create a symlink from `/var/www/html` to project's `./storage/app/public` **and** a symlink from `/some_other_folder` to project's `./storage/app/private`. In this case the question is can I write a file to a soft link of a folder and if I can, will the file really appear in the original folder of the symlink? If all of this is applicable, I am also interested if I can really create a symlink to a folder inside a Docker container...
- Set up Laravel Storage to write files externally instead of the folders inside the folder. In this case, the question is how should I configure Laravel *and* Docker to allow files to be written outside the container, putting them
  right into `/var/www/html` for **public** and `/some_other_folder` for **private**?

Is either of the thoughts correct/good/even achievable? Or is there any other way of solving the problem?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/

Answer (score 11):

I know the question is by far not the most recent on, but since i had the same problem and did quite some research myself until i got an idea:

I've started the php container using two bind mounts that work like the link created by artisan would:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  laravel:
    image: php
      volumes:
        - type: bind
          source: /path/to/laravel/project/
          target: /var/www/html/
        - type: bind
          source: /path/to/laravel/project/storage/app/public/
          target: /var/www/html/public/storage/
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```sh
docker exec -it my_container bash -c "cd public && ln -s ../storage/app/public storage"
```